# Remove display:none from my pagination code don't know from where its coming

Tags: css

```
<div class="clear">
    </div>
<div align =center  style ="display: inline !important;" ><?= $pagination?>       </div>
```

Its showing in inspect element

```
element.style {
display: none;
}
```

I dont know from where its taking this style

THis is the script which is creating problem

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#sbox2").hide();
 $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
$("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    var tname=$(this).attr('name');

    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
     return
    }
    else{
    $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
    $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    }
});



});
</script>
```

Comment: any script used to hide stuff?

Comment: Please provide sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this

```
PHP/HTML
<div align=center id="pagination"  style ="display: inline !important;" > <?= $pagination?> </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#content div").hide(); //replace with below script
$("#content div:not('#pagination')").hide(); //use this
```